# Rotating rigid curves hinged at intersection

Tags: geometry, multivariable-calculus

Plane (implicit) curves

$$ f(x,y)=0,\,g(x,y)=0\, $$

intersect at $ P_i(x_i,y_i) .$ We have  all curves

$$\lambda f(x,y) + (1- \lambda ) g (x,y)=0 $$

passing through and rotating about hinged point $P_i$ as $ \lambda$  values.

How is rotation angle related to $\lambda?$

Comment: What is $i$.?..

Comment: Unless the curves are both straight lines, I'm not sure how you could describe this transformation as a "rotation."

Comment: @MyGlasses symbol denoting intersection.

Comment: Are you assuming that both $f$ and $g$ have tangents at $P$?

Comment: @MichaelSeifert Angle between tangents at  invariant $P$ varies in rotation.

Comment: @ John Wayland Bales Yes  there  is real.tangent for each curve at real intersection point $P.$.

Answer (score 1):

If the functions $f$ and $g$ have non-vanishing gradients at the points $P_i$, then the angle between the tangents of the curves $f = 0$ and $g=0$ will be the same as the angle between the normals to the curves.  These vectors are given by the gradient of the function:
$$
\vec{n}(\epsilon) = \lambda \vec{\nabla} f + (1-\lambda) \vec{\nabla} g
$$
Define the angle between the tangent to the curve when $\lambda = 0$ and the tangent at arbitrary $\lambda$ as $\theta(\lambda)$.  This angle will be given by the familiar equation for the cosine of the angles between two vectors:
$$
\cos \theta(\lambda) = \frac{\vec{n}(0) \cdot \vec{n}(\lambda)}{|\vec{n}(0)||\vec{n}(\lambda)|} = \frac{\vec{\nabla} g \cdot (\lambda \vec{\nabla} f + (1-\lambda) \vec{\nabla} g)}{\left|\vec{\nabla} g \right|\left| \lambda \vec{\nabla} f + (1-\lambda) \vec{\nabla} g\right|}
$$
In the above expression, all of the gradients are to be evaluated at the point $P_i$.

Comment: Can it not be simplified using partial derivatives?

Comment: @Narasimham:  I haven't tried, but I suspect that the expression will look even more complicated if you explicitly write out the partial derivatives.  For example, the $|\vec{\nabla} g|$ in the denominator becomes $$ \sqrt{ \left(\frac{\partial g}{\partial x} \right)^2 + \left(\frac{\partial g}{\partial y} \right)^2},$$ which is pretty ugly-looking.  I'd personally prefer to stay with the expression in terms of the gradients.